# Pandas set values of multiple rows of a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe(`train`) that has an `Age` column in it. This column has missing values. I have merged it with another dataframe- `static_values` which also has an `Age` column. I am using the below lines to substitute the missing values for the `Age` column in `train` df.

```
predicted_vals = pd.merge(static_vals, train, on=['Pclass','Sex'])
# num of missing values
predicted_vals.loc[predicted_vals['Age_y'].isna(),'Age_y'].isna().sum() # 177
predicted_vals.loc[predicted_vals['Age_y'].isna(),'Age_y'] = predicted_vals.loc[predicted_vals['Age_y'].isna(),'Age_x']
```

After running the above lines, I run the following to see if the values have been substituted-

```
predicted_vals.loc[predicted_vals['Age_y'].isna(),'Age_y']
```

And this is the putput I get -

```
Series([], Name: Age_x, dtype: float64)
```

Its empty. No assignment has happened. The strange part is that when I check the values for the `Age_x` column after running the above lines, I get a blank there too.

```
>>> predicted_vals.loc[predicted_vals['Age_y'].isna(),'Age_x']
Series([], Name: Age_x, dtype: float64)
```

Below is what the column holds right before I run the lines where I am trying to assign the missing values

```
>>> predicted_vals.loc[predicted_vals['Age_y'].isna(),'Age_x'].head()
3     34.240964
8     34.240964
15    34.240964
25    34.240964
34    34.240964
```

I searched here for similar questions here but all deal with assigning a single value to many rows. I can't figure what's wrong here. Any help?

Comment: Hmmm, it is expected output, because if no `NaN`s values and filter them, get emty `Series`.

Comment: But the best is add some data sample.

Comment: It has missing values. Check line two in the first code block. Meanwhile, I'll add some data

Comment: Let me understand this; you want to simply assign for entries in column2 (('Age_y')), where there is a nan entry the value of column1 ('Age_x'), is that right? why don'y to just use the apply() function and use df['col2'] = df.apply(lambda f: f['col1'] if f['col2'].isnan() else f['col2'], axis=1)

Comment: @jezrael. You are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there actually a problem here? 
`predicted_vals.loc[predicted_vals['Age_y'].isna(),'Age_y']` should be empty because you have filled the values! Try `predicted_vals.loc[~predicted_vals['Age_y'].isna(),'Age_y']`

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative solution, which avoids merging and handling column name suffixes. We align the 2 indices and use `fillna` to map from `static_vals`.

```
predicted_vals = predicted_vals.set_index(['Pclass','Sex'])

predicted_vals['Age'] = predicted_vals['Age'].fillna(static_vals.set_index(['Pclass','Sex'])['Age'])

predicted_vals = predicted_vals.reset_index()
```

If you would like to do an explicit merge, [@jezrael's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48742943/9209546) is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
predicted_vals['Age_y'] = predicted_vals['Age_y'].combine_first(predicted_vals['Age_x'])
```